# JavaScript not running without developer console in IE (can't attribute to missing console)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, console

I'm writing a web application platform that serves JavaScript applications to a browser. Needless to say, I launch an application with a JS method after the document has loaded, but on IE9 nothing happens if the developer console hasn't been fiddled with.

This seems like the typical missing console problem, but I couldn't fix it by adding a check for console or removing console calls from the source code.

Can you guys spot where I'm going wrong?

- The site: http://eiskis.net/proot/pika/proot/
- JS source: http://eiskis.net/proot/pika/proot/assets/behavior

I'm serving multiple separate web apps with the same platform, so you can also check out the following (the problem appears the same all over):

- http://eiskis.net/proot/pika/baseline
- http://eiskis.net/proot/pika/docs
- http://eiskis.net/proot/pika/fails
- http://eiskis.net/proot/pika/helloworld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.keys is not supported in all versions of internet explorer : 
Please refer to the following : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys 
The following (from the source mentioned above) adds Object.keys to the browsers that do not support it :

```
if (!Object.keys) {
  Object.keys = (function () {
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        hasDontEnumBug = !({toString: null}).propertyIsEnumerable('toString'),
        dontEnums = [
          'toString',
          'toLocaleString',
          'valueOf',
          'hasOwnProperty',
          'isPrototypeOf',
          'propertyIsEnumerable',
          'constructor'
        ],
        dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length

    return function (obj) {
      if (typeof obj !== 'object' && typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null) throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object')

      var result = []

      for (var prop in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) result.push(prop)
      }

      if (hasDontEnumBug) {
        for (var i=0; i
```

In addition, your method of checking the existence of console is erroneous :

Try running (http://jsfiddle.net/PytAh/) in internet explorer: 

`if (console){
    alert("there");
} else {
    alert("not there");
}`

It will generate an error showing that console does not exist. 
You can replace it by :

```
if (window.console){
    alert("there");
} else {
    alert("not there");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you clarify what was wrong with the catch? It seemed to do the job on IE9 at least, since I couldn't catch the missing console again after running it.

Anyway, the Object.keys catch seemed to do the job, thank you very much. I created normalizing functions for these things so it's easy for me to take care of any more of these things in the future. You can take a look at them on the site now, type "proot.normalize" to the developer console.

Comment: Oh, and I'm not sure the Object.keys snippet did the job for IE8, for some reason. I removed the dependency from one of my libraries now, so it runs, but I'd still like to add the support if I could.

Comment: I think I would be able to help you better if you provide a small snippet demonstrating an example that fails with Object.keys even after the snippet has been implemented.

Comment: I was wrong, it does seem to work when I try tested it in console. I'll have to debug this more myself, but it's not a problem with this snippet itself.